# How can I choose a single dynamodb table as event type in Cloudtrail

Tags: amazon-web-services, amazon-dynamodb, amazon-cloudtrail

I plan to create a trail in `Cloudtrail` to capture all data events for a dynamodb table. But it doesn't allow me to select a single dynamodb table. It is greyed out in below screenshot. Is there a way to only capture one single table rather than all tables?

[image]

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You have to switch to advanced mode. Then you can specify custom event pattern in json, e.g.:

```
[
  {
    "name": "",
    "fieldSelectors": [
      {
        "field": "eventCategory",
        "equals": [
          "Data"
        ]
      },
      {
        "field": "resources.type",
        "equals": [
          "AWS::DynamoDB::Table"
        ]
      },
      {
        "field": "resources.ARN",
        "equals": [
          "<ARN-OF-TABLE>"
        ]
      }
    ]
  }
]
```